# background-origin: padding-box not working?

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` with `padding` on all sides. Inside the `div` I have a background image. I want the background image to respect the `padding` (by using `background-origin`). Why isn't this working?

I want the background image to respect / be inset by the padding (so that the padding is almost like a frame around the image).

```css
.hero_image {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 72px);
  background-color: rgb(0, 97, 111);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 72px;
  background-origin: padding-box;
  background-image: url("https://s7.postimg.cc/6vtowr3u3/salters_hill_old_logo.jpg");
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero_image"></div>
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s7nn0hep/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the result you are after you will need to change `background-origin: padding-box;` to `background-origin: content-box;`.

This is because the background is positioned *relative* to the padding box when you use `background-origin: padding-box;`, as you want to respect the padding you need to position it relative to the content box instead.

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0;
}
.hero_image {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 72px);
  background-color: rgb(0, 97, 111);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 72px;
  background-origin: content-box;
  background-image: url("https://s7.postimg.cc/6vtowr3u3/salters_hill_old_logo.jpg");
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero_image"></div>
```